# Bitbucket Webhook for private NPM or bit.dev

Tags: npm, bitbucket, webhooks, package-managers

Is it possible to create a ebhook for NPM.org (private) or Bit.dev?
I want to store my code in a bitbucket repository, after i merge a pull request i want the webhook to trigger and update the NPM package as well.

I know it is possible with packagist.
https://kevingoedecke.me/2018/08/24/update-packagist-with-github-webhooks-without-service/

Comment: Find a solution to this?

Comment: No I haven't looked into it

Comment: For now, the Bitbucket integration with bit.dev is in "coming soon" status.
I wrote a simple repo/tutorial on how to export during CI with Bit, it may help you:
https://github.com/teambit/bit-with-github-actions

Comment: Link is outdated, check https://kevingoedecke.com/2018/08/24/update-packagist-with-github-webhooks-without-service/